# How to find UIView origin using ratio?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have 2 `UIImageView`. Both `UIImageView` has the same size proportion. The first `UIImageView`'s size is always smaller or equal to the second `UIImageView`'s size.

On the first `UIImageView` I have a `UIView`. This `UIView` the user can place it anywhere on the first `UIImageView`.

I want to find the `x,y` of the second `UIView` that will be on the second UIImageView with same proportion as the first `UIView`.

Please look at this image to be clear. Please note that Rectangle 1 is first `UIImageView` and Rectangle 2 is second `UIImageView`.

[image]

What I've tried:

```
CGFloat xMultiplier  = imageView2.frame.size.width / imageView1.frame.size.width;
CGFloat yMultiplier  = imageView2.frame.size.height / imageView1.frame.size.height

CGFloat view2x = view1.frame.origin.x * xMultiplier;
CGFloat view2y = view1.frame.origin.y * yMultiplier;
```

My application is an application that users can choose stickers (`UIView`) and place it anywhere on their photo. The stickerView on the second image is not in the same place as stickerView in the second image

The resulting x,y for my code is close to where it should be but its not exactly where it should be.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you should get the factor ( which you are already doing correctly ) , but then you have to calculate it proportionally to Point1 ( to some point in View1 ) , for example

```
CGFloat yFactor = view1.frame.size.height / view2.frame.size.height;
CGFloat xFactor = view1.frame.size.width / view2.frame.size.width;


CGPoint pointInView2 = CGPointMake(pointInView1.x / xFactor,pointInView1.y / yFactor);
```

pointInView1 is the origin of Sticker in View1

if sticker2 is subview of view2 , then origin will be pointInView2

if sticker2 is not subview of view2 , and they have the same superview , the origin will

```
CGPointMake(pointInView2.x + view2.frame.size.width,pointInView2.y + view2.frame.size.height);
```

if there is any other hierarchy , you can use UIVIews method convertPoint ...

```
[view2 convertPoint:pointInView2 toView:sticker2.superView]
```

Comment: Thankyou for you answer. but it doesn't give the right x,y

Comment: check my updated answer , make sure you have proper hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

assuming that the rectangle 2 is merely a rescaled version of rectangle 1. the position of view 2 is :

```
xpos_view2 = xpos_view1/xwidth_Rect1 * xwidth_Rect2
ypos_view2 = ypos_view1/ywidth_Rect1 * ywidth_Rect2

View2.position = CGPoint(x:xpos_view2, y:ypos_view2)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Calculate Ratio from smallest iPhone device**

```
func ratioW(_ ofSize : CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let windowWidth = bounds.size.width

    let temp = 320/ofSize 

    return windowWidth / temp
}

func ratioH(_ ofSize : CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let windowHeight = bounds.size.height

    let temp = 480/ofSize 
    return windowHeight / temp
}
```